# why is it not saving graph in graphml format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graphml

I want to save the graph in graphml format

```
g=networkx.Digraph()
```

**graphs nodes ,edges and their weight formation**

```
networkx.write_graphml_lxml(g,'t1.graphml')
KeyError: <class 'list'>
```

Comment: What happens by changing the graph creation to `g = nx.DiGraph()` ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  I've got a few followup questions.  1st, can you tell us what version of networkx you're using (this can be found using `networkx.__version__`)? 2nd: I'm not able to reproduce your problem, so it would appear that something in how you put nodes etc into `g` matters.  Could you provide a [mcve]?  Thanks!

Comment: networkx will let you put anything into a node or edge attribute, but graphml is more limited in what it supports - it looks like you're passing in a list somewhere. Your best bet is to figure out where it is, and encode it into a string (e.g. `json.dumps(mylist)`) and save that string into the attribute instead.